# Zend Doctrine 1.2 foreignAlias is ignored in YAML schema file. Error during build-all cmd in Doctrine Cli

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, yaml, relationship

I have simple problem what I cannot understand why it's not working...
Server: latest ZendServer CE, ZF: 1.11.11, Doctrine: 1.2.2

YAML schema:

```
        Uzytkownik:
          tableName: uzytkownicy
          columns:
            id:
              type: integer
              fixed: false
          unsigned: true
          primary: true
          autoincrement: true
        uzytkownik_dane_id:
          type: integer
        login:
          type: string(64)
          notnull: true
        haslo:
          type: string(96)
          notnull: true
        email:
          type: string(192)
          notnull: true
        nazwa:
          type: string(64)
      relations:
        UzytkownikDane:
          local: uzytkownik_dane_id
          foreign: id
          foreignAlias: Dane
          foreignType: one

    UzytkownikDane:
      tableName: uzytkownicy_dane
      columns:
        id:
          type: integer
          fixed: false
          unsigned: true
          primary: true
          autoincrement: true
        imie:
          type: string(128)
        nazwisko:
          type: string(128)
        kraj:
          type: string(32)
        wojewodztwo:
          type: string(64)
        miejscowosc:
          type: string(128)
        adres:
          type: string(128)
        kod:
          type: string(16)
        telefon:
          type: string(16)
      relations:
        Uzytkownik:
          local: id
          foreign: uzytkownik_dane_id
```

Model generated via Doctrine Cli build-all-reload:

```
    hasOne('Application_Model_UzytkownikDane as UzytkownikDane', array(
                 'local' => 'uzytkownik_dane_id',
                 'foreign' => 'id'));
        }
    }
```

As you can see doctrine Cli ignored my alias and setup default: Application_Model_UzytkownikDane as UzytkownikDane... Why?
Secound thing is that (may it's important i don't know...) Doctrine Cli output me error when i build-all models form yml file:

```
    build-all-reload - Are you sure you wish to drop your databases? (y/n)
    y
    build-all-reload - Successfully dropped database for connection named 'doctrine'

    build-all-reload - Generated models successfully from YAML schema
    build-all-reload - Successfully created database for connection named 'doctrine'

    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'testdb.#sql-188_3a' (e
    rrno: 150). Failing Query: "ALTER TABLE uzytkownik ADD CONSTRAINT uzytkownik_uzy
    tkownik_dane_id_uzytkownik_dane_id FOREIGN KEY (uzytkownik_dane_id) REFERENCES u
    zytkownik_dane(id)". Failing Query: ALTER TABLE uzytkownik ADD CONSTRAINT uzytko
    wnik_uzytkownik_dane_id_uzytkownik_dane_id FOREIGN KEY (uzytkownik_dane_id) REFE
    RENCES uzytkownik_dane(id)
```

why? ofc all working relations working etc.. but alias not working and Cli outputs the error...
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the `foreignAlias` setting is not being respected, I'll check some code when I get home.

But I think the reason why you are getting the failed `alter table` response is because of this:

```
Uzytkownik:
  ....
  uzytkownik_dane_id:
    type: integer
    # This is missing the unsigned attribute, as set in `UzytkownikDane.columns.id`
    # Also it may not hurt to add the fixed attribute as well, although I don't think it will matter
```

MySQL expects the datatypes of both columns to be the same, so if one is flagged as unsigned and the other is flagged as signed, you will get the SQL error you posted.

**-- Update --**

According to [Doctrine 1.2 docs](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/yaml-schema-files.html):

> When specifying relationships it is only necessary to specify the relationship **on the end where the foreign key exists**. When the schema file is parsed, it reflects the relationship and builds the opposite end automatically. If you specify the other end of the relationship manually, the auto generation will have no effect.

I follow their guidelines and only establish the relation on the table which contains the foreign key, so give this a try:

```
Uzytkownik:
  tableName: uzytkownicy
    columns:
      id:
        type: integer
        fixed: false
        unsigned: true
        primary: true
        autoincrement: true
      uzytkownik_dane_id:
        type: integer
      login:
        type: string(64)
        notnull: true
      haslo:
        type: string(96)
        notnull: true
      email:
        type: string(192)
        notnull: true
      nazwa:
        type: string(64)
      relations:
        UzytkownikDane:
          local: uzytkownik_dane_id
          foreign: id
          foreignAlias: Dane # Set this if you want the UzytkownikDane to reference this as Dane
          alias: Dane # Set this if you want this table to reference UzytkownikDane as Dane (which I think is what you want)
          foreignType: one

UzytkownikDane:
  tableName: uzytkownicy_dane
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    imie:
      type: string(128)
    nazwisko:
      type: string(128)
    kraj:
      type: string(32)
    wojewodztwo:
      type: string(64)
    miejscowosc:
      type: string(128)
    adres:
      type: string(128)
    kod:
      type: string(16)
    telefon:
      type: string(16)    
  # No need for references here, they will be auto-generated by Doctrine
```

I tested the build-model and behaved as the Doctrine docs dictated.

Comment: I have AI set true, id column definition for Uzytkownik is copied from UzytkownikDane in my schema... but error still occurs.

Comment: additional code contains config init and Cli: http://www.copypastecode.com/225133/

Comment: I took a look at what I had last night, as I have a 1:M relationship between 2 of my models, but no alias. I am going to test the alias and get back to you.

Comment: I finally got some time to test today. Ill post my findings in a few hours.

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long. Diablo 3 was released and my schedule was a mess. I'll run some tests today and post my findings.

Comment: Updated with suggestion to fix the foreignAlias. Also I updated the original response concerning the FK constraint failing when trying to create the table. Let me know how it goes.